# Margin right does not work and falls out of bounds, although the parent is set to display flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, margin

I want to move the pictures of the rating stars to the right, but the indent falls out of the block.

I tried to set display flex to the parent, but it didn't help((

I'm trying to move the `RatingUserList` block

```css
.RatingUser {
  display: flex;
}

.RatingUserList {
  margin-right: 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
}

.RatingCell {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="NameAndRating">
  <p class="UserName">Юрий Петров</p>
  <!-- имя пользователя в профиле -->
  <div class="RatingUser">
    <ul class="RatingUserList">
      <li class="RatingCell"><img class="RatingImg" src="img/RatingStar.svg" alt=""></li>
      <li class="RatingCell"><img class="RatingImg" src="img/RatingStar.svg" alt=""></li>
      <li class="RatingCell"><img class="RatingImg" src="img/RatingStar.svg" alt=""></li>
      <li class="RatingCell"><img class="RatingImg" src="img/RatingStar.svg" alt=""></li>
      <li class="RatingCell"><img class="RatingImg" src="img/RatingStar.svg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's very hard to help you

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first time on this site and I didn't know how to add code. Now I've added it.

Comment: try this:`.RatingUser {
  display: flex;
   margin-left: auto;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're asking for.
I've used HTML stars to make them visibile. You'd have to replace them with your images.

```css
/* Added */
.NameAndRating {
  display: flex;
}

.RatingUser {
  margin-left: auto;
}
/* ---------- */

.RatingUserList {
  margin-right: 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
}

.RatingCell {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="NameAndRating">
  <p class="UserName">Юрий Петров</p>
  <!-- имя пользователя в профиле -->
  <div class="RatingUser">
    <ul class="RatingUserList">
      <li class="RatingCell">&#128953;</li>
      <li class="RatingCell">&#128953;</li>
      <li class="RatingCell">&#128953;</li>
      <li class="RatingCell">&#128953;</li>
      <li class="RatingCell">&#128953;</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```